# Eevee disable receiving light for an object

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, light, lighting

Im currently working on a Wormhole tunnel effect like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2WTH016rfk

Problem is in my scene I got objects which are flying through it and those emit light too. So if they fly through it, the tunnel gets lightened up.

The Wormhole in itself is more of a special effect and its own shadermaterial emits light already, but I dont want it to accept other lights... any ideas how to disable this in eevee?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with your Nodesetup and a render? The Node Wranglers Viewer Node is just an Emission Shader and should not receive light anyway, so this shouldn't be a problem in theory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I just use an emission node with a default value of **1.0**.

As you can see in the screenshot, the emission only affects the self object and not other objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I think** in blender you have to use the compositor to do that. Blender doesn't have a light excluder see this tut.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PByGtB_ahmw